# What are the registration requirements for US aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-registration

Where can the requirements for US aircraft registration be found?

What is the penalty for flying an aircraft without a valid registration?

What should someone do if they believe an aircraft to be operating without valid registration, and how could they determine this?

Somewhat related to this other question: 
[What is the pilot's obligation to verify a registration has not expired?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3534/what-is-the-pilots-obligation-to-verify-a-registration-has-not-expired)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where can the requirements for US aircraft registration be found?

The registration procedure is outlined in [FAA Form AFS-750-94, Information to Aid in the Registration of U.S. Civil Aircraft](http://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/aircraft_regn_forms/). See also the [full list of FAA registration forms](http://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/aircraft_regn_forms/).

> **3.** The owner of an aircraft must apply to the Aircraft Registration Branch, P.O. Box 25504, Oklahoma City, Oklahoma 73125-0504, to obtain a certificate of registration. The applicant must submit an Aircraft Registration Application, AC Form 8050-1, accompanied by evidence of ownership and a $5 registration fee.
>
> **Requirements for registration of aircraft** are contained in the [Federal Aviation Regulations, Part 47, “Aircraft Registration.”](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr47_main_02.tpl) (For sale by the Superintendent of Documents, U.S. Government Printing Office, Washington, DC 20402.)

Basically, the registrant (whether an individual or a corporation, trustee, etc., all of which are defined in Part 47) must be able to prove legal ownership of the airplane.

---

> What is the penalty for flying an aircraft without a valid registration?

The violator would be subject to any of the [standard FAA enforcement actions](http://www.aopa.org/Pilot-Resources/PIC-archive/FAA-Enforcement/FAA-Enforcement): administrative action (a "Warning Notice" or "Letter of Correction" which goes on your record), reexamination ("709 ride"), certification action (suspension or revocation), or civil/criminal penalties. The exact penalty would likely depend on the circumstances: whether the violation was intentional and the degree of the pilot's negligence under the FARs.

---

> What should someone do if they believe an aircraft to be operating without valid registration, and how could they determine this?

The [FAA's website recommends](https://www.faa.gov/contact/) reporting FAR violations by calling the FAA's toll-free telephone number, **1-866-TELL-FAA**.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to read [14 CFR part 47 - Aircraft Registration](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr47_main_02.tpl).

As for most penalties with the FAA, it can vary wildly, from a warning if it is a minor or technical infraction, potentially all the way to lifetime loss of license and criminal charges if done deliberately and maliciously.